# I designed an ATmega32U4 circuit, will it work?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, atmega, review, easyeda

Here is my schematic, drawn in EasyEDA:

[image]

The battery is the Sparkfun lithium-ion battery. I based the battery charger on the official one.

Will this work, or do I need to make some changes?

Comment: Schematic reviews are hard because if everyone notices a different thing, you can't decide which answer is most correct. Having said that, it likely won't work. Where does VCC come from?

Comment: If it works or not depends also on the layout really. If you correctly copied together parts of proven boards most of it would be ok. Please focus your question to parts where you have doubts. To be honest, such unspecific requests for design review feel a bit demanding to the point of being overbearing.

Comment: You might want to take some time to tidy up the schematic, especially enlarging the boxes so that the text is contained and has reasonable margins, and moving that "Reset Area" box so it isn't overlying any other boxes. There's lots of empty space you can use.

Comment: From the buttons being labelled A-G and the title including "Piano", I'm guessing that you want the circuit to output different audio frequencies. However, an [HNB09A03 buzzer](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Buzzers_Jiangsu-Huaneng-Elec-HNB09A03_C96102.html) only outputs a fixed frequency of 3 kHz. Maybe the buzzer is used for something else, but I thought it worth pointing out just in case.

Comment: Your "VCCPort" connection to C3 looks suspicious. Shouldn't "VCCPort" connect to VCC, and the left side of C3 be connected to Ground?

Answer (score 0):

Although the Atmega chip runs on any voltage from 2.7V to 5.5V, a voltage within the voltage range of your battery, it needs to be a regulated voltage. You are taking VCC directly from the battery. This is no good. You need a regulator between the battery and the Vcc pins. Something like a 3.3V output DC/DC convertor is a good choice since your input is a battery.

Every pin that says Vcc, should have a decoupling cap next to it between Vcc and Ground to filter noise. 0.1uF is a standard value for this.

Your buzzer is connected directly to the uC pins. Depending on the type of buzzer, this may draw too much current from the uC. Use a transistor to turn it on instead and possibly add a resistor in series. Check the datasheet.

You have USB signals on your board. These are high frequency. The board will work best if you lay out a proper ground plane on your PCB.

The switches could use a capacitor to help with debouncing the signal. Search for debounce circuits online.

You have an off board connector for SPI communication. This is usually hit or miss since it will pick up a lot of noise from the signal going off board and it will need to share a grounds with whatever board you connect to it. You can look into different communication protocols like rs485 or ethernet if you need to communicate with ICs far away on a different PCB.

Comment: May I ask why battery voltage won't directly work and why a regulator is needed? If you mean that the USB portion needs 3.0V to 3.6V to be compatible with USB devices, then mention it, don't leave the reason out. Otherwise, there is no need for a regulator. But frankly, I'd be more worried about there being no supply to AVR at all at this point.

Comment: The uC needs a steady voltage for timing and for proper IO readings. The crystal will not oscillate at a steady frequency if the voltage across it keeps changing. This will throw off the timing. Lets say you have 2.5V on an IO pin. The uC goes to read it but Vcc rises to 5V. What was a logic high a uS ago, is now considered a logic low becuase Vcc has changed. This will happen inside the chip as well and mess with the operation of the uC.

Comment: Yes, and the battery voltage is steady, between 2.7 to 4.2V. It has virtually zero output impedance, and helped by local bulk and bypass capacitors. The AVR and crystal will work steadily enough between those voltages. Of course all the other circuitry needs to follow the same voltage. You would obviously use 2.5V input voltages on a MCU that has supply voltages between 2.7 and 4.2V as that would be outside of specs. And, there are no voltages outside that. Sure, for USB, AVR requires certain voltage range. Sure, for certain frequency of operation, the AVR requires a certain voltage range.

Comment: When that buzzer turns on, you're going to see the effects of the "virtually zero output impedance" when a power spike on Vcc resets the uC.

Comment: I strongly believe that the lithium battery or wiring does not care much about if you turn on a load that draws only max 30mA DC if they are sensible. If it does, it's a wrong battery for the job, or otherwise damaged, or the wiring is not sensible.

Comment: Using a regulator for a uC is standard practice. The uC operation is undetermined if the voltage is not steady, spikes, or starts to oscillate.

Comment: Using a MCU directly from batteries is also a standard practice. Batteries are also less spiky voltage sources under load changes than regulators which will have undershoots and overshoots as response to load changes. For example, you turn on the 30 mA buzzer with battery power. Assume 1 ohm wiring and battery output impedance to MCU, which is absurdly high. The voltage change will be only 30 mV. A first order approximation with 10 uF bulk capacitor, it would take 10 us to voltage drop by 30 mV. Slope is 3 mV per 1 us. Even worse designs work just fine, just think of bike/camping lights.

Comment: Running an MCU directly off a battery is also standard practice, depending on the situation. Ultra-low power circuits wouldn't want or need to waste any power in a regulator for example.

Comment: *When that buzzer turns on, you're going to see the effects of the "virtually zero output impedance" when a power spike on Vcc resets the uC* A regulator won't help with that. Decoupling will. Regulators don't store energy. For the uC to reset, the VCC has to go below the brownout reset level. If the battery impedance is so high that it can't support this, the regulator won't help either. Batteries are pretty much the cleanest DC supplies you can get relative to their cost, as long as they are used properly. They have very low DC impedance.